# why main method in static nested class runs instead of outer class?

Tags: java, static, nested-class

In the give code snippet, only the main method of nested static class run, but not of the outer class. Why so?

---

```
package pack;

public class MyOuterClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main method of Outer Class...");
    }

    static class MyInnerClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("main method of Static Nested Class...");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: what runs is what you tell java to run... which leads to the question: how do you run your program? That should give you the answer.

Comment: What command line did you use to run it?

Comment: Which class did you provide as the Main class in the command to execute the program in Command Line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your command:

`java pack.MyOuterClass` => Output: **main method of Outer Class...**

`java pack.MyOuterClass$MyInnerClass` => Output: **main method of Static Nested Class...**

Answer (score 0):

the command `java pack.MyOuterClass` :- outer class main method
`java pack.MyOuterClass$MyInnerClass`:- nested static class main method.